# How might I get a JQuery "click" function to work without an arbitrary alert immediately preceding it?

Tags: jquery, click, alert

Sorry about the title; couldn't think of a succinct way to phrase my question.
I have a small JQuery script that makes two AJAX calls (to retrieve some arbitrary xml).
My problem is one that many others seem to have had, but with far less complex code. From what I've read, my problem is a race condition between the JQuery "click" listener and some other process. I've tried splitting the code into two separate scripts and "defer"ing the one with the "click" listener (and calling the deferred script at the bottom of the HTML body).
The code is:

```
function extractThread(){
    var xmlSource;
xmlSource = $(this).attr("id");
xmlSource = "xml/" + xmlSource;
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: xmlSource, cache: false, success: function(data) {
    setUpThread(data);
        }
    });
}

pub.setup = function() {
    var target, thread, posts;
target = $("#threadList");
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "xml/forum.xml", cache: false, success: function(data) {
    $(target).append("<ul></ul>");
    $(data).find("thread").each(function () {
        thread = $(this).find("title")[0].textContent;
        posts = $(this).find("posts")[0].textContent;
        $(target).find("ul").append("<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"threadName\" id=\""+ posts +"\">" + thread + "</a>");
        });
    }
    });
    /* works if: alert(anyMsg); */ 
    $(".threadName").click(extractThread);
};/*end setup*/

return pub;
}());

$(document).ready(GetThreads.setup);
```

Where extractThread calls some other arbitrary method.
I don't understand why there IS a conflict here; hasn't the ajax already returned success?
I've read numerous other questions in the same vein as mine, but I haven't been able to apply the suggestions given (maybe cos it's 7am, and I've been up waaay too long).
The general consensus seems to be that "adding alert() makes my code work" is an indication that there's an issue with the timing of some asynchronous events...
This is my first time posting on StackOverflow (or any programming board), and I'm very new to JavaScript in general, so if there's anything I could do to clarify my question, or anyone has any suggestions on cleaning up my code, I'd really appreciate it. 
Cheers, Sam.
Note: "far less complex" is referring to my code, not others'!

EDIT: (since I don't know how to "+1", or mark questions as solved):
Thanks for the replys; I never expected such a quick reaction.
The:
 $(document).on("click", ".threadName", extractThread);
Solution, provided by Artem, works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this below.  Ajax is asynchronous and therefore you can only call that `click` once the Ajax has returned.  Hence by putting it in the `success` callback it will only get run then rather than arbitrarily before then.  Putting an alert stops code execution and therefore would normally have given your Ajax call enough time to return successfully.

Hope that helps.

R.

```
function extractThread() {
    var xmlSource;
    xmlSource = $(this).attr("id");
    xmlSource = "xml/" + xmlSource;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: xmlSource,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            setUpThread(data);
        }
    });
}

pub.setup = function () {
    var target, thread, posts;
    target = $("#threadList");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/forum.xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $(target).append("<ul></ul>");
            $(data).find("thread").each(function () {
                thread = $(this).find("title")[0].textContent;
                posts = $(this).find("posts")[0].textContent;
                $(target).find("ul").append("<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"threadName\" id=\"" + posts + "\">" + thread + "</a>");
            });
            /* works if: alert(anyMsg); */
            $(".threadName").click(extractThread);
        }
    });
}; /*end setup*/

return pub;
}());

$(document).ready(GetThreads.setup);
```

Comment: I tried this, but my ide (I'm using dreamweaver) picks it up as a syntax error for some reason.
If this did work, would it still allow the  click event to be called at any time (after the ajax has "succeeded"): ie: is the success callback accessible at *any* time?

Comment: @user2697416
I had the click listener in the wrong place.  I have amended the code.   Hopefully dreamweaver will stop moaning! Yes it will trigger the click listener on the `.threadName` anytime after it was added as a consequence of a `success` callback from the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

As @rob-schmuecker already explained Ajax is asynchronous so it is very probable that you don't have any anchors with class treadName created yet at the moment when you attach your click event listener.

But you can attach another type of click listener that will work for nodes that created even after you added listener:

```
$(document).on("click", ".threadName", extractThread);
```

Comment: So what's happening here is that the "on" event can only be triggered when the ".threadName" class exists and can be "click"ed? That makes sense. I know it say's don't use the reply section for "thanks" but thanks indeed to both of you!

Comment: @user2697416 Yes, you understood it correctly. I used to use .live() handler before. According to documentation: _Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future._ But now this method is deprecated and send us to .on() So for your case you need attach an event to the selector in the future. That is why .on() is good for your case.